# Alert moment formatted date in safari browser

Tags: typescript, safari, momentjs

I have a typescript code:

```
var inputDate = '2018-09-13 21:00:53';
var date = new Date(inputDate);
var formattedDate = moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
alert(formattedDate);
```

In **Safari** browser it alerts `NaN-NaN-NaN NaN:NaN:NaN`.

How to `alert` values?

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLjQx/142250/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve it:

```
var inputDate = '2018-09-13 21:00:53';
inputDate = inputDate.replace(' ', 'T')
var date = new Date(inputDate);
var formattedDate = moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
alert(formattedDate);
```